# UITabBarController has a truncated badge

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I get the behavior from the picture below. Basically the badge from the second tab it's under the third UITabBarItem image. The image from third tab it's composed from the camera icon and the green background.

I am assigning an image using:

```
UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
tabItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"albumsSelected"]
                       imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
tabItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"albums"]
               imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Is there a way to fix this UI bug?

[image]

Comment: then you also attach code how did you set a cam image in tab-bar? do you think any-buddy can do reply on this without see the code?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472960/ios-7-uitabbaritem-badge-z-index

Comment: Thanks you a lot! Unfortunately that question hasn't a too suggestive title